# limit of a complicated function

Tags: calculus

I want to calculate $\lim_{u\uparrow 1}\frac{\Phi(\Phi^{-1}(u)+\theta^{-1}\sigma^{-1}\ln 2)-1}{1-u}$, where $\theta<0,\sigma>0$. And the following is my steps,
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\lim_{u\uparrow 1}\frac{\Phi(\Phi^{-1}(u)+\theta^{-1}\sigma^{-1}\ln 2)-1}{1-u}&=\lim_{u\uparrow 1}\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{\partial \Phi^{-1}(u) }{\partial u}\exp(-\frac{t^2}{2}),
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where $t=\Phi^{-1}(u)+\theta^{-1}\sigma^{-1}\ln 2$.
By the property of inverse function, moreover
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\lim_{u\uparrow 1}\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{\partial \Phi^{-1}(u) }{\partial u}\exp(-\frac{t^2}{2})&=\lim_{u\uparrow 1}\frac{-1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac{t^2}{2})\frac{1}{\Phi^{'}(\Phi^{-1}(u))} \\
&=\lim_{u\uparrow 1}-\exp(-\frac{t^2}{2})\exp(\frac{{t^{'}}^2}{2}),
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where $t^{'}=\Phi^{-1}(u)$. Simplifying it we get
\begin{equation}
\lim_{u\uparrow 1}-\exp(-\frac{t^2}{2})\exp(\frac{{t^{'}}^2}{2})=-\infty.
\end{equation}

But in my settings, this should take the value from -2 to -1, I am wondering what's wrong here?